# Push http callbacks into array from foreach

Tags: arrays, angularjs

What I'm trying to make is a comparator for statusus, I made an array of names for the names of the channels that I want to compare:

```
var stations = [
    "BasicChannel",
    "PixelChannel",
    "GoldenChannel"
];
```

Now, through using a foreach loop I want to do a HTTP call with all of those statusus:

```
angular.forEach(stations, function(channel) {
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: channel + ".php"
    }).success(function(data) {
        data.name = channel;
        $scope.channels = data; 
    });
});
```

Now, the problem is that I have is that every time I do a HTTP call, it overrides the other ones.

Is there a way to get these in an object, or an array maybe?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming `$scope.channels` is what you're overriding. Why not do `$scope.channels[channel] = data`?

Comment: Then I woudn't be able to do "ng-repeat='channel in channels'", i think

Comment: @ChongTang Make this into an answer and I'll accept it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate two array in Javascript. Like this:

```
$scope.channels.concat(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can insert the data at top of the array.

```
$scope.channels.unshift(data);
```